# Add prefix to the file in S3 getting written by Kinesis Consumer

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am writing data to file in s3 using kinesis consumer. I observed that Kinesis Consumer was overriding the file. Therefore, I added timestamp directory and writing data to s3 timestamp directory which resolved overriding issue.

But still I would like to know how to add prefix and/or suffix to the file getting created by Kinesis Stream in S3 buckets. I am using following code for writing to the s3,

```
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/"
    , <baseOutputDir>
    , <eventsOutputSubDir>
    , <year-value>, <month-value>, <day-value>, <hour-value>, <timestamp-value>)
 , classOf[GzipCodec])
```

I need some help regarding adding prefix and/or suffix to the files getting created in s3.

Comment: What's the current name of the output file?

Comment: @XavierGuihot file name is like part-00000.gz

Comment: And you have several part files and the name you provide in saveAsTextFile is given to the folder containing them?

Comment: @XavierGuihot As you can see that I am using coalesce with argument 1 which means I am writing only file at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an answer to add prefix to the resultant files in S3/HDFS which is following,

Instead of using saveAsTextFile, I used following,

```
hadoopConf.set("mapreduce.output.basename", new Date().getTime+"")
rddstr.coalesce(1).map(str => (null, str))
      .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/"
        , baseOutputDir
        , eventsOutputSubDir
        , dt._1, dt._2, dt._3, dt._4), classOf[NullWritable], 
        classOf[String], classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, 
        String]], hadoopConf)
```